# ¿Por qué el puntero en C++ no cambia el valor?

Tags: c++

Estoy estudiando C++. Vengo de C# y de Java; en estos lenguajes cuando modifico una referencia en un método con la palabra ref, modifico el valor de la variable en memoria: esto lo uso para hacer resizes de arreglos. Un ejemplo sería:

```
void Resize(ref int[] array,int longitud){
   array= new int[longitud];
}
```

Esto lo intenté recrear en C++ de esta manera:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void resize(int* arr);

int main()
{
  int* arr = new int[1];
  arr[0] = 1;
  cout << arr[0] << endl;
  resize(arr);
  cout << arr[1]; // imprime números raros, se supone que debe imprimir 2
  cout << arr[0]; // imprime 1
  return 0;
}

void resize(int* arr){
  arr = new int[6];
  arr[1] = 2;
}
```

Pero al final del resize el arreglo viene siendo el mismo que el arreglo anterior al resize. ¿Cómo funcionan los punteros aquí en C++? ¿Por qué no cambia el valor de memoria por el nuevo array que le estoy asignando a esa posición de memoria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fíjate que en C# tienes que utilizar `ref` para que el array cambie de longitud.

Esto es así porque una cosa es el puntero (la reserva de memoria en sí) y otra los valores que almacena.

En la versión de C++ únicamente estás pasando el puntero, por lo que los cambios en dicho puntero son únicamente locales (es decir, aquellos cambios que afectan a la memoria del puntero, no a los valores alamcenados por el puntero).

Para poder hacer una nueva reserva necesitas pasar un puntero doble:

```
void resize(int ** arr){
    *arr = new int[6];
    *arr[1] = 2;
}
```

O bien podrías pasar una referencia al puntero

```
void resize(int* & arr){
    arr = new int[6];
    arr[1] = 2;
}
```

Comment: ¿Has cambiado tu imagen de usuario, eferion? :O

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no, se cambió sola hace unos meses ... llevaba tantos años con ella que lo mismo estaba caducada y los admins me dieron una nueva para que no me sentara mal :)

Answer (score 1):

Saber lo siguiente te ayudará a entender el problema:

- Un [puntero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) es una variable cuyo valor es una dirección de memoria.
- El operador [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) reserva memoria en el montón, llama al constructor del objeto y devuelve su dirección de memoria.
- Por defecto, las funciones reciben una copia del objeto. Similar a lo que se considera como *pasar por valor* en lenguajes de alto nivel.

Dicho esto, puedes ver que en tu función estás pasando una copia del puntero (la dirección de memoria que contiene).

```
void resize(int* arr){
  arr = new int[6];
  arr[1] = 2;
}
```

El código *funciona*, pero no produce el resultado esperado porque el parámetro de la función `resize` y `arr` en la función `main` son variables independientes. Así que los cambios que hagas dentro de la función `resize` se perderán al salir de la misma.

---

Ahora sí, vamos con las 2 soluciones:

- Usar un puntero a la variable que quieres modificar. Es decir, la función recibirá la dirección de memoria de la variable, permitiéndote modificar su valor.

  ```
  void resize(int** arr){
      delete[] *arr;
      *arr = new int[6];
      *arr[1] = 2;
  }

  // En la función main
  resize(&arr);
  ```
- Usar una [referencia](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). Esto es lo más cercano conceptualmente a *pasar por referencia* en lenguajes de alto nivel. La ventaja es que no necesitas desreferenciar ningún puntero y el código es más limpio.

  ```
  // Referencia a variable de tipo int*
  void resize(int*& arr){
      delete[] arr;
      arr = new int[6];
      arr[1] = 2;
  }

  // En la función main
  resize(arr);
  ```

---

Si bien ya está respondida tu pregunta, es importante mencionar que:

- Los programas de C++ no poseen un recolector de basura como los de C# o Java .
- La memoria no se recupera automáticamente durante la ejecución del programa. Debes liberarla con el operador [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) para que no ocurran *fugas de memoria* o te quedes sin memoria disponible.
- [La mayoría de sistemas operativos modernos liberan la memoria al terminar la ejecución del programa](https://stackoverflow.com/q/654754/13419694). No deberías preocuparte si un programa reserva poca memoria y su ejecución es breve.